# Bootstrap Modal Jquery not rendering or showing correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I am having issue rendering the bootstrap modal using Jquery this is what I have so far:

HTML

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Do you want to save changes you made to document before closing?</p>
                <p class="text-warning"><small>If you don't save, your changes will be lost.</small></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$('#update_modal').on('click', function() {
        console.log("clicked");
        jQuery.noConflict();
        $("#myModal").modal('show');
    })
```

there is a button which has the id as "update_modal".

Here is a [Snapshot](https://gyazo.com/4f908c1fa8b939f993e797e89f348a4b) of how it look like. As you can see its not rendered everything correctly and I cannot click any where to close the modal off too.

Please can someone tell me if I have missed anything off. Thank You

Comment: Please share your entire `HTML` structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I have replicated the problem https://jsfiddle.net/z26sxpvk/2/

```js
$('#update_modal').on('click', function() {
  $("#myModal").modal('show');
});
```

```css
#myModal {
  z-index:0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button id="update_modal" type="submit">
Open Modal
</button>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Do you want to save changes you made to document before closing?</p>
                <p class="text-warning"><small>If you don't save, your changes will be lost.</small></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Problem is happening because the `modal`'s `z-index` is less than `modal-backdrop`.

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/z26sxpvk/3/

```js
$('#update_modal').on('click', function() {
  $("#myModal").css({
   'z-index': 1050
  }).modal('show');
});
```

```css
#myModal {
  z-index:0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button id="update_modal" type="submit">
Open Modal
</button>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Do you want to save changes you made to document before closing?</p>
                <p class="text-warning"><small>If you don't save, your changes will be lost.</small></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Just increase `z-index` value for `modal`.

```
$('#update_modal').on('click', function() {
  $("#myModal").css({
    'z-index': 1050
  }).modal('show');
});
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

This one works for me, added `aria-hidden="true"` in first `<div>`

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModal" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Do you want to save changes you made to document before closing?</p>
                    <p class="text-warning">
                          <small>If you don't save, your changes will be lost.</small>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Your modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTlgb.png)

I tried your code and its showing perfectly and can to be closed with the button.
I assuming you to try showing and hiding modal via attriubutes before, with class="modal" and data-target="#myModal". If your modal is not showing perfectly like your code above, maybe that of this categorize :
1. Placement modal is wrong.
2. Or upgrade your bootstrap framework.
Try with attributes before, then with javascript like your code or improvement.
Hope this can help you.
Keep your spirit :D .